# Unable to create Azure API Management instance

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create an Azure API Management instance as described in this article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/api-management-get-started/

I fill in the URL, region, organisation etc.
After clicking the check button I see an entry added and its status set to 'Activating...' after a few seconds.
However it stays in this status for a few hours and then the status changes to 'Failed'.
I've tried this in two of our subscriptions and two different regions, but none are working.

Am I missing some prerequisites or am I skipping something?
Any directions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...just 5 minutes after posting this question my instance is created in Central US. Appearently something is not correctly setup for the West Europe region. Sorry for bothering you guys!